# Why does react 18 warn using createRoot inside the container?

Tags: reactjs, react-18

I'm using React 18 and nextjs and I made a kind of render function like this

```
export const showAlert = (props: AlertProps) => {
  const container = document.getElementById('alert') // it will catch <div id="alert"></div> inside _document.tsx
  if (container) {
    const root = createRoot(container)
    root.render(<Alert {...props} />)
  }
}
```

And I want to use this function like this

```
const handleClick = () => {
 if (error) {
  showAlert({
   type: "error",
   text: "Error !"
  })
 }

}
```

But react warn this behavior

[image]

Anyone knows why React warn using of `createRoot` for the render function ?

Comment: It seems that you are using the `createRoot` elsewhere. You should use it only once and provide the root already created to your function using either a prop or another kind of variable.

Comment: Yes you're right. It seems that createRoot must be called only once.

Answer (score 0):

During runtime, createRoot should be called only once